# iOS - how to increase height of first row of UITableView only if Table is empty?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am new at iOS development.

I want to check if my table is empty. If it is, I want to :

---

Increase height of the first row and display `"No new messages!"`

**OR**

Get rid of the table and just display `"No new messages"` in the center of the page.

---

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Let's assume you have an array from which you want to populate the table view. This is a pretty standard way for populating table views. Let's call this theoretical array `dataArr`.)

In your data source:

```
- (NSUInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tv numberOfRowsInSection:(NSUInteger)section
{
    if ([dataArr count] == 0) {
        // empty table
        return 1;
    }
    return [dataArr count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"someCellID"];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"someCellID"] autorelease];

    if ([dataArr count] == 0) {
        // empty table
        cell.textLabel.text = @"No new messages";
    } else {
        // configure as normally
    }
    return cell;
}
```

In your delegate:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tv heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip
{
    if ([dataArr count] == 0) {
        // empty table
        return 88.0f; // 2 times the normal height
    }
    // else return the normal height:
    return 44.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:1] == 0) {
        return 200;//some other height
    }else{
        return 44;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what do i need to do to set the text?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have an array of messages you are attempting to display

You can define custom height for cells with the function

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       if (messages.count == 0)
           return 80;
       else
           return 44;
 }
```

and then, when you are creating the cells: (make sure the "no new messages" cell has a different cell identifier than the regular cells, so that your cell re-use won't mess things up)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (messages.count == 0) {
        // create the "No New Messages" cell
    }
    else {
        // create regular cells
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to check against your data source to see if you have no messages in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

For example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([data count] == 0) return 100;
    else return 44;
}
```

Comment: where do I set the data variable?

Comment: Well you would need some type of array or data structure to fill the table.  Whatever you are using for that should be data.